# google app engine query opimization

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, query-optimization

I am trying to do my reads and writes for GAE as efficiently as possible and I was wondering which is the best of the following two options.

I have a website where users are able to post different things and right now whenever I want to show all posts by that user I do a query for all posts with that user's user ID and then I display them.  Would it be better to store all of the post IDs in the user entity and do a get_by_id(post_ID_list) to return all of the posts?  Or would that extra space being used up not be worth it?

Is there anywhere I can find more information like this to optimize my web app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The main reason you would want to store the list of IDs would be so that you can get each entity separately for better consistency - entity gets by id are consistent with the latest version in the datastore, while queries are eventually consistent.

Check datastore costs and optimize for cost:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing

Getting entities by key wouldn't be any cheaper than querying all the posts.  The query makes use of an index.

If you use projection queries, you can reduce your costs quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

There is several cases.

First, if you keep track for all ids of user's posts. You must use entity group for consistency. Thats means speed of write to datastore would be ~1 entity per second. And cost is 1 read for object with ids and 1 read per entity.

Second, if you just use query. This is not need consistency. Cost is 1 read + 1 read per entity retrieved.

Third, if you quering only keys and after fetching. Cost is 1 read + 1 small per key retrieved. Watch this: [Keys-Only Queries](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Keys_Only_Queries). This equals to projection quering for cost.

And if you have many result, and use pagination then you need use [Query Cursors](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Query_Cursors). That prevent useless usage of datastore.

The most economical solution is third case. Watch this: [Batch Operations](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Batch_Operations).

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a list of id's because they are stored with your entity, a call to ndb.get_multi (in case you are using NDB, but it would be similar with any other framework using the memcache to cache single entities) would save you further datastore calls if all (or most) of the entities correpsonding to the keys are already in the datastore.

So in the best possible case (everything is in the memcache), the datastore wouldn't be touched at all, while using a query would.

See this issue for a discussion and caveats: http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=118.